# Crafting a mirrored shifting drum for motorcycle gearbox

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, cad

I would like to reverse the gearing of my Husaberg FS 650e motorcycle so that by pressing the shifting pedal the gearbox changes up instead of down to the first gear.

There are many solutions on the market consisting of linkages that redirect the movement of the shifting pedal. Unfortunately this is not possible on my bike.

First of there is no ready to buy solution, secondly there is not enough free space around the shaft that would make this approach feasable.

So I am wondering if theoretically a mirrored/inversed shifting drum would accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Can you add a clear photo of the gearbox / gear-lever area of your bike please?  Most of the ones on the googler are a bit lacking in specific detail in that area.

Comment: It's possible to find stock or aftermarket for GP-Shift for many bikes, but it seems to always be done by modifying the lever: https://www.cycleworld.com/sport-rider/should-you-reverse-your-shift-pattern-riding-skills-series/ https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpZFX.jpg

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question you must furnish a complete kinematic model of the entire shifter mechanism, and then study it to determine exactly how to reverse the indexing action by recutting the shifting drum.

Neither of these tasks will be straightforward.

You would be better off designing a simple 2-gear reverser mechanism which would bolt on to the shifter shaft and transmission housing, or by asking yourself just how important it really is to reverse the shifting action on that bike.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am aware that engineering a special purpose shifting drum is a job of it's own. I am just wondering, if one would flatten the surface of the drum and then create a mirrored Version of it and Project it back would reverse the gearing.

Comment: I am was thinking of the following steps: 1) use a 3D scanning technology to create a virtual copy of the orignal drum 2) mirror the surface using CAD software 3) use a metal 3D printer to create a prototype and test it. But this procedure could only work if a 1:1 mirror would create the desired effect of reversing the shifting mechanism.

Comment: Please let us not get into a discussion about the pro & contra about reversing the gearing.

Comment: @Matze, I think your idea of using 3D scanning and manufacture tools is feasible (and not all that expensive any more).  I'd be concerned about the longevity of a Laser Sintered  stainless steel part. One milled out of a billet of steel would likely be expensive but can be achieved on a 4 axis lathe/mill.

Comment: @Matze, also be cautious about how the 3 cam tracks on that cylinder are aligned with each other, it is possible that the delicate meshing requires one gear to move slightly ahead of another to avoid collisions.  If this is the case then simple mirroring might not be enough to make it work properly.  You might need to rotate one or two rings to be a few degrees opposite to their current position.  This is actually a really interesting problem.

Comment: @Wossname thx for replying. The idea about a laser sintered steel part was more about getting rapidly to a prototype. If the prototype fits and works on an open gearbox it can be send to a company who produces that part.

Comment: @Wossname, so you think mirroring the flattened Surface would make it reverse? Is there a way to simulate or model it with reasonable afford?

Comment: @Matze, Modelling the part in CAD (Fusion 360, Solidworks etc...) is trivial, but actually measuring it accurately will be tricky because of the curves and angles on the interior of a curved 3D slot.  Radii and angular offsets will be critical.  Covering the cylinder in ink and rolling it across a surface (it would look like a tyre print) would give you at least something that you can take measurements from using a digital caliper.  That might be enough to prove or disprove the feasibility of your task.  The paper could then be transferred to CAD and wrapped around a cylinder and cut out.

Comment: I don't have machine-shop experience but given that the blank cylinder should be fairly routine is there no way to use a pantograph milling machine in mirror mode to copy the pattern from the original to the mirrored?